# Software / Site for Comparison Lists

Tags: database, gui, comparison, database-browser

Wondering if anyone has a suggestion for either a website or a piece of software useful for recording information on things you're trying to compare?

Examples:
Looking for a house - would be nice to be able to have a list of candidates where each record contains:

- (Text) Address
- (Image) Main Photo
- (Image) Floorplan Photo
- (Image Gallery) Slideshow of other photos
- (Text) Price Range
- (Text) Description
- (Text) Comment

But looking for something flexible where the particular fields can be defined by the user. I guess basically a database CRUD app that's pre-built, customisable and with some auto-formatted GUI?

Ideally it would allow you to:

- Define a type of *item* with an arbitrary number of fields (text, numbers, images, etc)
- Be able to fill out a form to create a new item, adding it to a master list
- Be able to see the master list in some kind of graphical view (each item as a card, or as a row in a table, etc)
- Be able to see each item in a full-page GUI view with all fields present & editable (maybe some way the view can be customised by dragging fields into specific orders?)
- Be able to scroll from one item to the next

It's something I've used MS Access for in the past but it's a bit tedious and I'm wondering if anyone knows of anything simpler?

Comment: Welcome on the site. Great first question, IMHO.